# Make a new column based from CASE and GROUP BY result

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have table like this called, table `test`:

```
+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------------------+--------+
|                      1 |      2 |
|                      1 |      2 |
|                      1 |      2 |
|                      1 |      3 |
|                      2 |      2 |
|                      2 |      2 |
|                      2 |      2 |
|                      2 |      3 |
|                      3 |      2 |
|                      3 |      3 |
|                      4 |      2 |
|                      5 |      2 |
|                      5 |      3 |
|                      6 |      2 |
+------------------------+--------+
```

I want to group by `id_laporan_rekomendasi` and make a new column when in column `status` there is value `3`. so if there is no value `3` in column status, then the value would be `0`, but if there is value `3` than `1`.

I expect the result would be like this

```
+------------------------+------+
| id_laporan_rekomendasi | test |
+------------------------+------+
|                      1 |    1 |
|                      2 |    1 |
|                      3 |    1 |
|                      4 |    0 |
|                      5 |    1 |
|                      6 |    0 |
+------------------------+------+
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi, 
COUNT(distinct case when t1.status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as test
FROM test t1
GROUP BY t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi
```

But i got the result like below

```
+------------------------+------+
| id_laporan_rekomendasi | test |
+------------------------+------+
|                      1 |    2 |
|                      2 |    2 |
|                      3 |    2 |
|                      4 |    1 |
|                      5 |    2 |
|                      6 |    1 |
+------------------------+------+
```

Does anyone could help me with this table ?

Comment: `COUNT(...)` counts everything in `...` except `NULLs`.  That is `0` is counted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  In MariaDB, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi, 
       MAX( t1.status = 3 ) as test
FROM test t1
GROUP BY t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi;
```

MariaDB (and MySQL) treat boolean expressions as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So this does what you want.