# Make a new column based from CASE and GROUP BY result part 2

Tags: sql, mariadb

Previous question : [Make a new column based from CASE and GROUP BY result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235114/make-a-new-column-based-from-case-and-group-by-result)

From the previous question i got the result like below

```
+------------------------+------+
| id_laporan_rekomendasi | test |
+------------------------+------+
|                      1 |    1 |
|                      2 |    1 |
|                      3 |    1 |
|                      4 |    0 |
|                      5 |    1 |
|                      6 |    0 |
+------------------------+------+
```

The query is just like below (thanks to [**Gordon Linoff**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49235139/7840345)):

```
SELECT t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi, 
       MAX( t1.status = 3 ) as test
FROM test t1
GROUP BY t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi;
```

Now, ihave other problem. on left side of column `id_laporan_rekomendasi` there is a column callled `id_laporan`, so the table would looks like this.

```
+------------+------------------------+------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | test |
+------------+------------------------+------+
|          3 |                      2 |    0 |
|          3 |                      6 |    1 |
|          8 |                      3 |    1 |
|          8 |                      4 |    1 |
|          7 |                      1 |    1 |
|          7 |                      5 |    1 |
+------------+------------------------+------+
```

I need to group by again `id_laporan` and add a new column called `test2` , like if from column `test` have at least value `0` than the result will be `0`, if there is no value other than `0` (ex. `1` ) it will give us value `1` in column `test2`.

I have tried many possible queries: like

```
SELECT t2.id_laporan, MAX( t2.test = 1 )
FROM (SELECT t1.id_laporan, t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi, MAX( t1.status = 3 ) as test
FROM test t1
                        GROUP BY t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi) t2
                        GROUP BY t2.id_laporan
```

But it gives me result

```
+------------+--------------------+
| id_laporan | MAX( t2.test = 1 ) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          3 |                  1 |
|          7 |                  1 |
|          8 |                  1 |
+------------+--------------------+
```

I changed the max into `MAX (t2.test = 0 )` , it given me result like this:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| id_laporan | MAX( t2.test = 0 ) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          3 |                  1 |
|          7 |                  0 |
|          8 |                  0 |
+------------+--------------------+
```

I Expect the result would like below:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| id_laporan | test2              |
+------------+--------------------+
|          3 |                  0 |
|          7 |                  1 |
|          8 |                  1 |
+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution,

I just simply change the `MAX` function, to `MIN` function, so it would be like

`MIN( t2.test = 1 )`

**FULL QUERY**

```
SELECT t2.id_laporan, MIN( t2.test = 1 )
FROM (SELECT t1.id_laporan, t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi, MAX( t1.status = 3 ) as test
FROM test t1
GROUP BY t1.id_laporan_rekomendasi) t2
GROUP BY t2.id_laporan
```

With [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) function, it will return `0` when column `test` had value more lower than `1`.